# Laptop carrying case for 15 inch laptop

Tags: case

I have an old [Targus carrying case](http://targus.com/us/meridian-ii-toploading-laptop-case-tst031us) that was gifted by my employer a long time ago. It's decent, but bulky. I'm looking for a case that can hold a 15 inch laptop, plus a few additional things (safety glasses, a notebook, a few writing instruments) and isn't big, bulky and heavy.

Criteria:

- Can hold a laptop (15 inch) plus charger
- Can hold a wireless mouse
- Can hold a small fold up umbrella
- Can hold safety glasses, a notebook, pens/pencils
- Provides basic protection against being tossed into a passenger seat in a vehicle
- Is not bulky. My current bag is 7-8 inches wide. This is too bulky.

Budget for this approximately $50.

Comment: This is a test question to see how the community feels about cases/accessories. This scope being discussed in this [meta post](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/267/57).